# Issue with JSON Parsing in Python Script for Autodesk CheckEntitlement Endpoint

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am writing to report a recurring issue I've encountered while attempting to interact with the CheckEntitlement API endpoint via a Python script. I've observed that when invoking the endpoint, I occasionally receive a parsing error, which seems to suggest that the expected JSON response is not being returned under specific circumstances.

When executing the script, the following error is produced:

> HTTP Request failed: Expecting value: line 4 column 1 (char 3)

This error suggests that the JSON parser is attempting to process an empty string or a malformed JSON response.

**Troubleshooting steps taken:**

- Verified the HTTP response code to ensure a `200 OK` status is received.
- Printed the raw response text prior to JSON parsing to confirm the actual response.
- Checked the API documentation for expected behavior and potential changes in the response format.

**Current impact:**
This issue is hindering the script's functionality, leading to inconsistent performance and impacting our workflow.

**Request:**
I kindly ask for your assistance to:

- Verify if there are any known issues with the endpoint that could lead to such a response.
- Provide guidance or a workaround to ensure reliable JSON responses from the endpoint.
- Confirm if there are any additional headers or request parameters that need to be included.

```py
# Python code snippet to demonstrate the request and handling of the response
def is_entitled(user_id, app_id):
    url = f"https://apps.autodesk.com/webservices/checkentitlement?userid={user_id}&appid={app_id}"
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}  # Explicitly accept JSON response

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()

        # Even if the content-type is not application/json, try to parse it as JSON
        # because sometimes servers send JSON with the wrong content type
        entitlement_response = response.json()
        is_valid = entitlement_response.get('IsValid')
        message = entitlement_response.get('Message')
        return is_valid, message

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"HTTP Request failed: {e}")
        return False, f"HTTP Request failed: {e}"
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Response content that caused the error: {response.text}")
        return False, f"JSON Decode Error: {e}"


# Test the function with an actual user_id and app_id
print(is_entitled('0', '1'))
```

it respond correctly only in case i write the app_id equal to "0"

Comment: That code does not do anything with json.  Please update the question to show the actual code that has the error, and the full error message.  Also the raw response text.

Comment: Thanks for response I have updated the post. and added the code.

Comment: The response text is still missing

Comment: Now it workks after I Have updated the request code to be : 
```def is_entitled(user_id, app_id):
    try:
        response = requests.get(f'https://apps.autodesk.com/webservices/checkentitlement?userid={user_id}&appid={app_id}')
        return response.json()['IsValid']
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An error occurred: {e}" ```